# How can I debug a Dart AppEngine app

Tags: google-app-engine, dart

I'm now able to run a Dart app using

```bash
gcloud --verbosity debug preview app run app.yaml
```

and also to deploy and run on AppEngine

```bash
gcloud --verbosity debug preview app deploy app.yaml
```

but I haven't found a way to connect a debugger to the Dart app running on the development server.

I found http://dartbug.com/21067 but still couldn't find a way to make it work.

See also https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/cloud/OK1nJtg7AjQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2015-02-27

The app can be run without Docker and then be debugged like any Dart command line application:
Source. https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/cloud/zrxgOHFz_lA/q5CdLLQPBAgJ

> The API server is part of the App Engine SDK, and we are using it for
> running tests in the appengine package. If you look at
> https://github.com/dart-lang/appengine/blob/master/tool/run_tests.sh
> you will see that it expects the environment variable
> APPENGINE_API_SERVER.
>
> The API server is in /platform/google_appengine/api_server.py
>
> and takes a number of arguments. I just tested running it like this:
>
> $ $CLOUD_SDK/platform/google_appengine/api_server.py \    -A
> dev~test-application \   --api_port 4444 \   --high_replication \
> --datastore_path /tmp/datastore
>
> To run an app engine application outside the normal development server
> requires that a number of environment variables are set. This worked
> for my application:
>
> $ GAE_LONG_APP_ID=test-application \   GAE_MODULE_NAME=default \
> GAE_MODULE_VERSION=version \   GAE_PARTITION=dev \   API_PORT=4444 \
> API_HOST=127.0.0.1 \   dart bin/server.dart
>
> In the Dart Editor you cannot set environment variables for each
> launch configuration, so they have to be set globally before starting
> the Dart Editor. In WebStorm it is possible to have run configuration
> specific environment variables.
>
> This simple setup will of cause not support everything the normal
> development server support. Some of the issues are:
>
> - Only one application at the time as it is always listening on port
>   8080 (can easily be made configurable)   * The users API (mocking this
>   shouldn't be that difficult)   * The modules API   * No health-checks
>   (should not be a problem)   * All HTTP headers are direct from the
>   client (no x-appengine- headers)   * The admin web interface is not
>   available   * Probably other stuff as well
>
> This is all experimental, but it is one solution for a simpler
> developer setup, which of cause does not match the deployment
> environment as closely as the development server.
>
> Running the API Server using Docker is also possible as the image
> google/cloud-sdk with the Cloud SDK is on hub.docker.com.
>
> Use the following Dockerfile
>
> FROM google/cloud-sdk EXPOSE 4444 ENTRYPOINT
> ["/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/api_server.py", \
> "-A", "dev~test-application", \   "--api_port", "4444", \
> "--high_replication", \   "--datastore_path", "/tmp/datastore"]
>
> Build and run
>
> $ docker build -t api_server . $ docker run -d -p 4444:4444 api_server
>
> Change API_HOST above to 192.166.59.103 (of wherever your Docker
> containers are) and run.
>
> Regards, Søren Gjesse

#### Update 2014-11-27

Debugging from DartEditors debugger started working with the bleeding Dart build `1.8.0.edge_042017`.
I assume that the next dev build (probably `1.9.0-dev1.0`) will include the related fixes as well?

Detailed steps how this works can be found here: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/cloud/OK1nJtg7AjQ/u-GzUDI-0VIJ

- Build a custom Docker image with the latest Dart dev build `1.8.0-dev.4.6`.
  The Dart team is actually preparing an easy way to do this yourself (see https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_docker)
- Installe the latest bleeding_edge on the host system (using this script https://gist.github.com/zoechi/d240f56a32ed5649797f or manual download from http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/be/raw/latest/editor/darteditor-linux-x64.zip)
- Add this to the `app.yaml` file

```yaml
env_variables:
  DBG_ENABLE: 'true'

# disable health-checking because this is so annoying during debugging
vm_health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
```

See [How to disable health checking for `gcloud preview app run`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145997) for more details about customizing health checking.

- Launch the server code of your app with `glcoud --verbosity debug app run app.yaml` or `glcoud --verbosity debug app run app.yaml index.yaml`
- Wait until the Docker container is ready (check with `docker ps` if the `Command` column shows a value starting with `/dart_runtime/dart_`
- Open DartEditor
- Open Menu `Run > Remote Connection...`

  - Connect to: `Command-line VM`
  - Host: `localhost` if you don`t use` boot2docker`or the IP address returned by the command`boot2docker ip`
  - Port: `5005`
  - `Select Folder...` select the directory which contains the source code of your project.
  - Click `OK`
  - Set breakpoints and continue as usual.

#### Old

A first step is using the [Observatory](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/observatory/) which includes a browser based debugger UI.

To make this work add the following lines to the `app.yaml` file

```yaml
network:
  forwarded_ports: ["8181"]
```

This might be useful as well to make the `server.dart` wait until we had the chance to set breakpoints using the observatory.

```dart
env_variables:
  DART_VM_OPTIONS: '--pause-isolates-on-start'
```

`boot2docker` gives us the Docker ip (192.168.59.103) and after starting with `gcloud preview app run app.yaml` we can connect to `http://192.168.59.103:8181` which should open the Observatory GUI.