# Dart editor "source not available"

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I have the following basic code:

```dart
import 'package:jwt/json_web_token.dart';

main() {
  final jwt = new JsonWebTokenCodec(secret:'***'); 
  print(jwt.isValid('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2NmYy5hdXRoMC5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoiZ29vZ2xlLW9hdXRoMnwxMDc2MTcxNDk0MjIzMjU3MTU5MTciLCJhdWQiOiJ5a2h5NVJVbEpNSGw4Tzc0bGJ3Z29GZVVkUkI0VzZKRiIsImV4cCI6MTQxNjUzNTk3NCwiaWF0IjoxNDE2NDk5OTc0fQ.K_xAuG_rIAFe-zFFqn8SqXby3aqAkRJP2HrOjMnNUu0'));
  print(jwt.decode('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2NmYy5hdXRoMC5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoiZ29vZ2xlLW9hdXRoMnwxMDc2MTcxNDk0MjIzMjU3MTU5MTciLCJhdWQiOiJ5a2h5NVJVbEpNSGw4Tzc0bGJ3Z29GZVVkUkI0VzZKRiIsImV4cCI6MTQxNjUzNTk3NCwiaWF0IjoxNDE2NDk5OTc0fQ.K_xAuG_rIAFe-zFFqn8SqXby3aqAkRJP2HrOjMnNUu0'));
}
```

I then step inside the jwt package and set a breakpoint in the decode function.
When I try to run my code I get the message: "Source not available
Source not available for JsonWebTokeCodec.decode() ", which is strange since I stepped into the code to set the breakpoint. Is it not possible to set a breakpoint in an imported library?

Could it be my project structure that messes things up? The file is called `server.dart` and is in a folder called `bin`. There is also a `app.yaml`, `Dockerfile` and a `package.json` file in the root dir of the project. (I started out following the appengine example)

Edit: Im running it directly from the dart editor (the green play button, which I guess does `pub serve`), not using the appengine package at all. I also deleted `app.yaml`and `dockerfile`and the problem still persists. I also tried creating a new project (shelf template project) but was still not able to see the source code when the editor breaks on a breakpoint in imported code.

Comment: How did you connect the debugger. This is not straight-forward with an AppEngine app.

Comment: If you don't run this with the `gcloud` tool (AppEngine development server) it is probably a problem with your project structure or maybe with the pub package cache.

Comment: Hard to tell. How does your `server.dart` and `pubspec.yaml` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running a dev version of Dart 1.8, when I reinstalled Dart 1.7.2, the issue disappeared.

Comment: It is possibly that just reinstalling solved it. I always use bleeding edge and didn't have such an issue for several months (there was a bug in earlier versions which caused this in some situations but is solved for a while).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because debugging is not yet supposed to work for Dart AppEngine applications.

The related bug should be fixed but the used `google/dart-runtime` Docker images is still Dart 1.7.2 which doesn't contain the fix.

See also

- [How can I debug a Dart AppEngine app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807828)
- http://dartbug.com/21067
- https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/cloud/OK1nJtg7AjQ

Comment: Hi, I have updated by question a bit to make it clearer. I was running the project using pub serve