# How to disable health checking for `gcloud preview app run`

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to disable health checking when running the development server for manages VMs locally (`gcloud preview app run app.yaml`)?

This health checking causes me headaches during debugging.

I tried to add `health_check` settings to `app.yaml` like shown in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/managed-vms/ :

```
health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
```

and tried different values for

```
  check_interval: 5
  timeout: 4
  unhealthy_threshold: 2
  healthy_threshold: 2
  restart_threshold: 60
```

but none of these changes did work.
`enable_health_check: False` seems to be ignored and so are most of the other settings (some cause an error) see https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11491

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a comment from the issue you provided:

> There's also an existing bug about the dev server (gcloud preview app
>   run) not respecting the health_check setting. It's still using the old
>   and deprecated 'vm_health_check'. To get your settings to take effect
>   in the dev server you'll need to use vm_health_check for now.

So just use for now:

```yaml
# health_check: # not yet supported, use instead
vm_health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
```

or change one of the following settings

```
  # check_interval: # this is an error in the documentation, use instead
  check_interval_sec: 5

  # timeout: 4 # didn't work with vm_health_check
  unhealthy_threshold: 2
  healthy_threshold: 2
  restart_threshold: 60
```